# Metsudah Publishers - Do they have an official webstore?

Tags: jewish-books

Does Metsudah Publishing Company have their own official webstore? I can only seem to find private Judaica and book webstores that sell their products, but not an official Metsudah webstore. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked around and they seem to be associated with [Jonathan David Publishers](http://www.jdbooks.com/) but when I checked the website out they don't seem like they sell Metsudah products. I would check out [Israel Book Shop Publications](https://www.israelbookshoppublications.com/store/pc/showsearchresults.asp?customfield=2&SearchValues=345) or [The Judaica Place](http://www.judaicaplace.com/search/brand/Metsudah-Publications/) as they seem to sell all the Metsudah publications products available.

I think the The Judaica Place sells their products at a cheaper price after briefly looking at the product prices.

So until a Metsudah publishers official website opens up, I think going to one of the two websites listed to order the Sefarim you want can be useful for the time being.

Hope this helps.