# Are Metsudah Siddurim permananently out of print? (Specifically, Askenaz)

Tags: product-recommendation, prayer-book, nusach-ashkenaz

I've websearched all over for both the everyday and the Shabbat Metsudah siddur -- the seforim sellers are out of stock or have only nusach Sefarad. Used copies are expensive (for "acceptable") or exorbitant, which is usually a sign that something's not being printed.

Does anyone have any information that those siddurim will be printed again? (Or not?)

-- Many thanks!

PS -- Thank you for all the information I've found here in the past without needing to ask a question!

Comment: i've seen them very reasonably priced used

Comment: Where? The only ones I see below $50 are in the worst condition ("acceptable"). Most others are more expensive (up to $250 and more) and located in Europe - not possible for me.

I'm just looking for the normally priced edition, not a collector's edition.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) ejb and thanks for this first question. Glad you decided to join officially. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: @ejb i see them for sale in seforim groups on facebook

Answer (score 2):

The weekday siddur is available in [Lehmanns](https://www.lehmanns.co.uk/metsudah-linear-siddur-weekday-ashkenaz-compact-size-paperback.html?gclid=Cj0KCQiAip-PBhDVARIsAPP2xc0YSWSH2afZFONejq7-O6E8sCJ1WF0Xiueuj9KYH_kjzABOMCRKNysaAnSPEALw_wcB) albeit in compact size if that helps.

[Here](https://seforimcenter.com/Metsudah-Linear-Chumash--Complete-Shabbos-Siddur__p-9027.aspx) has the combined Chumash and Shabbos siddur.

There also appears to be the Shabbos edition available on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0076O17FK) (again pocket-sized), although there is only one left in stock.

Comment: Thank you for this, but none of those options are what I'm looking for. Ordering from Lehmann's is impractical because of shipping costs to the US and the method they use. The combined edition translates the Chumash but not the siddur. The edition on Amazon is the first 1983 edition, not the second 2007/2014 edition.

I'm looking for the latest edition in hardcover.

Comment: Aha perhaps you might want to edit your question to specify this? Best of luck with the search!

Comment: Ah! I thought about whether I had mis-specified my initial question. But (not to be pilpul) I didn't ask where to find them. I only asked whether anyone had any publication information.

-- Some people assumed I was "really" asking for copies.  But (to your point) if I were, I definitely would have specified which edition, publication year, binding, and (always) condition! 

-- I'm a scientist by training and a Jew by everything. I'm careful with the details.

Comment: Sure no problem - I'm not pointing the finger. Hatzlocho

Answer (score 1):

I had a [similar question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/75601/11486) years ago about metsudah publications, i don't believe they are in print anymore. you can still find their products on various judaica and seforim websites, but as you mentioned the only siddurim you could find were in nusach sfard. this is probably because the sites are selling what products that are left over from whenever metsudah stopped printing. given that the target market for the metsudah siddur don't daven nusach sfard they probably didn't sell as well as the siddurim in nusach ashkenaz. that being said, i still see them being sold in acceptable condition on both ebay and facebook groups, so i would look there. for example [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/234381754666?_trkparms=amclksrc%3DITM%26aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20160908105057%26meid%3D1e0729bb8f3f49b582af6e6319d2d624%26pid%3D100675%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D15%26sd%3D234381754666%26itm%3D234381754666%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2380057&_trksid=p2380057.c100675.m4236&_trkparms=pageci%3A8beb2876-79ad-11ec-8c4a-727fbaee23ab%7Cparentrq%3A75d94d6417e0ad343a9f780afffc64ec%7Ciid%3A1) is a good condition weekday ashkenaz siddur on ebay for $23.  i would contact israel mizrahi who runs [this famous ebay shop](https://www.ebay.com/str/jewishbookshop) and definitely check out the groups on facebook, there are always rare or out of print books there for good prices. hatzlacha rabba in your search

Comment: THANK YOU! This is very helpful. I do look at many online sites like Amazon, Addall (which includes many global Amazons, Abebooks and a number of European sites), the big seforim stores, but not usually eBay or Facebook. (Well, I do search eBay for collector's items, but I didn't think the Metsudah Siddurim were collector's items!) -- I should spend more time at eBay. Facebook I refuse to join, but if I can look and buy there (or at least find contact information) I will definitely do that.

Comment: @ejb I understand about facebook i recently took a break from it because it's a toxic environment but i do miss the jewish groups on there. if you have a friend have them post for you but facebook is one of the best places for buying and selling seforim, it's almost worth making a burner account just to participate. ebay is great for buying seforim i almost never buy my books new because you can so frequently find them used for a good price and in good condition on ebay